# Disabling password change requirement on 1st login to Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, ssh, login, password, sd-card

I setup a Pi 4 once with Ubuntu Server & was having issues with SSH not prompting me to change my password the 1st time I logged in.

So I researched for awhile & found a way to disable that via connecting video & a keyboard & doing something in the initial shell that came up when Ubuntu Server loaded up on my Pi 4.

Pretty sure I entered a command in on the boot up screen & was golden.

Or if I could change something on the Pi SD card similar to adding the blank SSH file. Editing some sort of config that'd work too I haven't plugged the SD into this Pi 4 yet.

Here are the files on the boot portion of my SD card for the Pi 4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSJLV.png

Naturally I wasn't smart enough to save the info I found so now that it comes time to do it again I'm having troubles finding it.

All my searches for info have led me to similar but starkly different questions & answers about enabling SSH keys & how to force password changes for users.

So the question is how do I disable the requirement to change the ubuntu:ubuntu user on 1st login?

Would very much appreciate the assistance if anyone knew

Comment: @matigo Thanks very much for the suggestion I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done by disabling `cloud-init`. There are two ways you can do this:

1. Create an empty file named `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`
2. Modify your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` parameters to include `cloud-init=disabled`

The first option can be done from any machine by writing the file to the SD card where you installed the OS. The second should be done from the Raspberry Pi with a keyboard and monitor attached as you'll need to run the `update-grub` command after changing the configuration.